# Spreading Spark executors evenly across the cluster when running on Yarn?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark application that has 30 executors that all generate significant network I/O. When I run it on my Hadoop cluster, all executors get scheduled on the same couple of nodes. How can I force the executors to be run on as many different nodes as possible, ideally in different racks?

I know YARN supports placement constraints (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/PlacementConstraints.html) so something like `myapp=30,NOTIN,NODE,myapp` should work (let's ignore rack anti-affinity and running the application when I don't have 30 nodes with sufficient capacity for now). But I've looked at the documentation for running Spark on YARN and I have to idea how to pass this placement constraint to YARN when submitting my Spark application

Comment: Hey have You got the solution of this issue, I am looking at something similar.